# unable to run sql query against oracle table in R

Tags: r, rodbc

I can run this query in sqlplus against an oracle table, it works I get results back:

```
SELECT * FROM KEYNOTE_PRD WHERE KEYNOTE_PRD."Site"='High Frequency NY Traffic'
```

but I try to same with the following code within R:

```
tryCatch({
  ch=odbcConnect("<id>",pwd = "<passwd>")
  sql<-c("SELECT * FROM KEYNOTE_PRD WHERE KEYNOTE_PRD."Site"='High Frequency NY Traffic'")
  res<-sqlQuery(ch, sql)

},error = function(e) {
  print(odbcGetErrMsg(ch))

  print("retrive or connect to the db")
})
odbcClose(ch)
```

It does not work. I think it does not like the double quotes within double quotes (KEYNOTE_PRD."Site"). Any ideas how would I get around this?

Comment: Are the double quotes part of your variable name? (than you have to escape them `\\"`)

Comment: Or you could use sprintf, paste, cat, or any of the other functions to interpolate strings.

Comment: @sgibb, I did this, still did not work: sql<-c("SELECT * FROM KEYNOTE_PRD T WHERE T.\\"Site\\"='High Frequency NY Traffic'")

Comment: Does Site really have to be quoted? I don't know much about the Oracle SQL specifications, but I've never been able to use double quotes inside queries for Oracle from R.

Comment: @Joran, I tried to use it without the double quotes around site, I get invalid identifier. I dont know how to tacke this.

Comment: What about single quotes?

Comment: no single quotes does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help someone who is not familiar with the Oracle. The asnwer was very simple.
I changed the column names to capital letters and this problem resolved. This must be an oracle thing.

```
tryCatch({
  ch=odbcConnect("<id>",pwd = "<passwd>")
  sql<-c("SELECT * FROM KEYNOTE_PRD WHERE KEYNOTE_PRD.SITE='High Frequency NY Traffic'")
  res<-sqlQuery(ch, sql)

},error = function(e) {
  print(odbcGetErrMsg(ch))

  print("retrive or connect to the db")
})
odbcClose(ch)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same type of issue where the column names were lower and I had no control over the tables. The solution was to escape the quotes with single \ character. It worked like a charm.